# How do i populate a Sql database in a Visual Basic 2010 DataGridview?

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview

I'm using the code below to populate data from my server tables into my vb application. unfortunately I cannot get it to populate the data, it only displays the test table I entered during vb database creation. Any ideas will be appreciated. Thanks!

Open up the student locator

```
Dim sql As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM database.dbo.table", cnn)
Dim stud_Data As DataSet = New DataSet()
Dim DataAdapter1 As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter()
DataAdapter1.SelectCommand = sql
DataAdapter1.Fill(stud_Data, "Student")
StudentListDataGridView.DataSource = stud_Data
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `stud_Data` is a `DataSet`, you need to tell the `DataGridView` `DataSource` which table to bind to.

try;

```
StudentListDataGridView.DataSource = stud_Data.Tables[0]
```